# Select top rows from DF per category without unique ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

INPUT

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'location_Id':['1a', '2a', '3a', '4b', '5c'], 'area':[1,1,1,2,2]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'GlobalID':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'quantity': [10,12,14], 'area':[1,1,2]})
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
df3= pd.DataFrame({'location_Id':['1a','2a','4b'], 'GlobalID':['a', 'b','c'],
                   'quantity': [10,12,14],  'area':[1,1,2]})
```

CONTEXT

I want to select the top N rows with the lowest locationsID from each area in df1, where N is the rows of that area in df2, and fill those with information from the other df2. Preferably in a relatively efficient manner.

Things I considered:

- splitting the DF1, adding some counter to each area, doing the same for df2, and then join on both counter and area (seems excessive)
- using something like `head(len(df2.loc[area = x]))` but I will lose the information from df2 and it is not very elegant...
- I guess I need to join based on the minimal value of `GlobalID`. Grouping by strings is very time consuming. So perhaps I should replace those with numbers?

Comment: how does `2a` get a globalID of b?

Comment: They both have an area code of 1, and the lowest location ID is matched with the lowest globalID, the second lowest (2a) with the second lowest GlobalID (b) per area. But maybe I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 1):

First, let's extract the the letter from the location id and pass this into a new variable.

The key functions are `str.extract` and `pd.merge`

```
n = 2
df1a = df1.join(df1['location_Id'].str.extract('(\D+)'))\
       .rename(columns=({0 : 'GlobalID' }))\
       .groupby('area').head(n) 


  location_Id  area GlobalID
0          1a     1        a
1          2a     1        a
3          4b     2        b
4          5c     2        c
```

---

Next, let's join and drop any NA rows:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df2,df1a,on=['GlobalID','area'],how='left').dropna()


  GlobalID  quantity  area location_Id
0        a        10     1          1a
1        a        10     1          2a
3        c        14     2          5c
```

Comment: Although the output seems to be a bit different than mine, it did got me thinking about different solutions. Thanks :-)